# Function to Return Multiple Tables

Tags: python, function

I am trying to have a function to do a predictable operation on a table and then return the output- it looks a lot like this

```
def func(table):
    return(table)

Table1 = func(Table1)
Table2 = func(Table2)
Table3 = func(Table3)
```

How do I structure the function to work like this?

```
Table1, Table2, Table3 = func(Table1, Table2, Table3)
```

Or better yet,

```
tables = [Table1, Table2, Table3]

tables = func(tables)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [comprehension list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
tables = [func(table) for table in [Table1, Table2, Table3]]
```

Or [map](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map):

```
tables = list(map(func, [Table1, Table2, Table3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tables = [func(t) for t in (Table1, Table2, Table3)]
```

Comment: You could increase the pedagogical value of this answer if you expanded a bit on what is going on